# performance of custom controls

Tags: asp.net, performance, controls

In terms of performance. Is it a good idea to build your own data grid (assuming you have the time) having in mind that you will create one that match perfectly your need? Getting rid of many unnecessary properties and methods. The rendered page might be smaller making the download faster?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties and methods of a server control have no direct relationship with the size of the rendered HTML.  Simply removing methods won't make the slightest difference in the size of your download. In my experience, the .NET controls work well enough.  If you encounter a performance problem, you can always drop in a different implementation later.

Answer (score 0):

As ASP.NET already includes the Repeater control and the DataList control, both of which allow you to specify the HTML output of the control, there is little need to create a new control for performance reasons.